# while sending data through post request using request module in nodejs got error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var request = require('request');
var postData = querystring.stringify({
    msg: 'hello world'
});
var request = require('req')

var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8000,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': postData.length
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));

    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('BODY:', chunk);
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
});
```

when i run this code I am getting cannot find 'req' module .I could see all the modules are properly installed in package.json and i did npm install too.Is there any problem in the code ?

Comment: When you get the error `cannot find 'something' module` means that you are doing a `require('something')` and this "something" doesn't exist. Also, in your code, you are declaring `var request` 2 times

Comment: now i m not able to see my data that i sent using post request using postman ...any wrong in the code ?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of this line: `var request = require('req')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete `var request = require('req');`

Comment: i  removed it but still getting error ...run the code i m getting response

Comment: if you can tell what the error is, it would be helpful @srikantht

Comment: events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.30.37.23:8000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)

Comment: You need to make this request opposite to proxy. Just pass the proxy host-name 
    `var options = {
       hostname: 'proxy'
   }`